# Can i use package method in graphql scheme?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Using this package - https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-likeable im trying to set number of likes to the comment type. Can u plese tell me, its real to use this method inside scheme without custom query?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wknKN.png)

```
type Comment {
    id: ID!
    comment: String!
    created_at: String!
    updated_at: String!
    likeCount: Int ########## something like this
}
```

I think its a really silly question but i cant find the answer)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that packages has an `Accessor`, so it may work as you already have your code. But if you want to use a method, just use [`@method`](https://lighthouse-php.com/4.18/api-reference/directives.html#method) directive.

Comment: Enzo, Thank you! 

I did not pay attention to this directive, sorry for my english, ur the best, Happy New Year )